# Max return parameter limit for HtmlPage.Window.Invoke method

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What could be the maximum limit of string values return from the following code?

is there is any limit on that application?

string o = (String)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallMe", "data here!!");